# Did Argentine President Juan Peron grant free access to the radio, the press and two soccer stadiums to a preacher called Tommy Hicks in 1954?

Tags: history, politics, christianity, latin-america

The title is a summary of claims I've read from several informal sources. For example, [this site](https://romans1015.com/1954-argentina-revival/) claims:

> It was in this environment that **Tommy Hicks was welcomed into the presidential office**. After Hicks informed the president what he was asking permission for [...] **and the president then gave Hicks and the evangelism committee their requests**:
>
> 1. **Use of the 45,000 seat Atlantic Stadium**
> 2. **Free access to state radio and press**
> 3. **Freedom to preach anywhere they wanted**

> **The evangelistic services began in the 45,000-seat Atlantic Stadium on April 14, 1954**, with around 6,000 in attendance (it lasted 52 days).

> It wasn’t long till the Atlantic Stadium’s 45,000 seats were maxed out, without even standing room being left. Crowds gathered for blocks around the stadium in every direction. To accommodate those outside the stadium, loudspeakers were installed so they could hear the Gospel message that was being preached every night. **Out of necessity, the services were then moved to the 110,000-seat Huracán Stadium on May 22, which also began to overflow**

Similarly, the description of this [amazon product](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B079HXKFRZ) claims:

> He suggested to the local church committee the possibility of **hiring a 25,000-seater stadium and employing the press and radio to advertise the meetings**.
> This seemed absolutely absurd but **Tommy Hicks**, unwavering in his faith, **made arrangements to visit the Argentine dictator leader, President Juan Peron**. [...] which secured the availability of the Atlantic Stadium with a seating capacity of 25,000.
> **Soon overwhelming crowds forced them to relocate to the Huracán Football Stadium with a seating capacity of 110,000, which also overflowed**.

And [this site](http://www.evanwiggs.com/revival/history/tommyhicks.html):

> The next day the guard greeted Tommy and his interpreter cordially **and escorted them to President Peron’s door**.  **The President greeted Tommy** and his interpreter and after asking them to be seated, asked the reason for them coming.  Pastor Hicks carefully explained to Peron the plans for the city – wide salvation – healing crusade planned. [...] **He also asked for full rights for the evangelicals to meet in stadiums and arenas of the nation**. [...] **At this meeting President Peron sat down and signed the total freedom for the evangelical church in Argentina**.

And lastly, [this site](http://voiceofhealing.info/04_other%20ministries/hicks.html):

> Tommy Hicks returned the next day and was soon ushered into the presence of this feared leader. **He quickly explained that he wanted to conduct a salvation-healing campaign in a large stadium, with press and radio coverage**. [...] Needless to say **Peron gave Tommy everything he requested**. **The Atlantic Stadium with a seating capacity of 25,000 was rented. Soon overwhelming crowds forced them to relocate to the Huracane Football Stadium with a seating capacity of 110,000**.

Are there reputable sources either confirming or refuting whether [Juan Peron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Juan_Per%C3%B3n) ever granted free access to the radio, the press and the Atlantic and Huracán stadiums to a foreign preacher named Tommy Hicks and his evangelism committee in 1954?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I'm mostly a lurker here and don't have enough rep on this stack to downvote, but my guess is that you could read the accepted answer to [the meta question you asked](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4636/33095) for reasons

Comment: @PCLuddite but isn't this a rather historical question? It's just a matter of confirming whether Juan Peron had a skin disease before and no skin disease after.

Comment: Brief search for Juan Peron and "skin disease" only found (a) multiple retellings of this account of Tommy Hicks and (b) dermatology papers referencing the Hospital Italiano de Buenos Aires whose street address is Pres. Tte. Gral. Juan Domingo Perón 4190, C1199 Buenos Aires, Argentina. adding  "psoriasis" adds a reference to "He suffered from a mild form of psoriasis that required medicine that also made him look good in photos." from scandalouswoman.blogspot.com. If Peron ever had "a persistent and disfiguring skin disease ... no longer allowed photographs" it left little biographical trace.

Comment: @SpiritRealmInvestigator Even "confirming whether Juan Peron had a skin disease before and no skin disease after" does nothing to answer your question

Comment: @motosubatsu - check out the last edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The edited question as it stands on 24 December may be better suited to the History SE site, since it amounts to "Did Tommy Hicks hold some well-attended evangelical meetings in Buenos Aires after meeting with the Argentinian president?" A biography of Peron available for online borrowing (https://archive.org/details/peronbiography00page/page/296/mode/2up) supports this with some interesting context, in a chapter titled "At War with the Church":

> Peron’s speech shattered the peaceful coexistence between Peronism and
> the church that had been coming apart for some time. For example, by
> executive decree Peron had eliminated from the list of government
> holidays certain Catholic holy days as well as widely celebrated
> feast days such as March 19 (Saint Joseph) and June 29 (Saints Peter
> and Paul). The Congress was considering bills to legalize prostitution
> and divorce, the latter advocated by several deputies from the women’s
> branch of the Peronist party. The hierarchy did not resist the loss of
> the holidays, but made clear its firm opposition to the proposed
> legislation.
>
> In 1954 the breach widened. The incident involving the Basilio Scientific
> School repeated itself in a slightly different form when an
> obscure North American faith healer held a series of well-attended
> revival meetings in Buenos Aires in May and June. Theodore Hicks,
> also known as Brother Tommy, visited Peron and made several
> appearances at the Casa Rosada during the run of his performances.
> According to one source, Eva Peron Foundation ambulances brought sick
> people to the services. Although Catholics complained that Hicks’
> public evangelical meetings violated both the constitution and
> federal laws, the authorities made no effort to stop him.
>
> On July 11, a group of lay Catholics met in the city of Rosario to
> found a Christian Democratic party. There were no political luminaries
> of note among them, nor did they represent any organizations with
> large memberships. Yet the president viewed this development with
> considerable alarm.

So as described there the meetings took place in the context of a widening rift between the Catholic and Peronist powers.